# Where are all of the basic JavaScript & HTML TypeScript types documented?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm essentially looking for documentation of the [src/lib](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/src/lib) directory in TypeScript itself: where can I find the type documentation for `HTMLInputElement`, or `Array`? There are a *lot* of basic types, some of which with un-guessable names, and I can't find a central reference that lists what they are. If I want to say that some function's inputs match the attributes of an input element, where do I look for where 'the attributes of an input element' are exposed in TypeScript's base types?

Comment: I would assume they're using the names provided by the spec. https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

Comment: I find the official spec hard to read sometimes so I tend to use the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) instead.

Comment: The TypeScript definitions do not mirror MDN or whatwg. For example, the "HTMLElementEventMap" type appears in neither.

Comment: I think I found it https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L6713 - no idea if this is documented somewhere though

Comment: That's the linked directory in the question, which is about whether there's documentation for those files.

Comment: Well there's my classic "didn't read the question properly" skill at work.

Comment: I'm almost convinced the are generated from mdn https://github.com/microsoft/TSJS-lib-generator/blob/master/inputfiles/mdn/apiDescriptions.json